# dc.js Is it possible to have a table of over 32 columns?

Tags: dc.js

Creating a table of over 32 columns is causing an error, I assume this is because of the dimension limit. I do not need all columns to interact with crossfilter, some are purely information.
Is it possible to create a table with upto 32 interactive columns and additional passive ones?

Comment: Can you please share your error and code? In a dc.js table, can't you use the accessor for the column or the `format` property of a column to display whatever you want? If you are defining more than 32 dimensions in your Crossfilter, that will indeed not work priority version 1.4, but I don't think you should really need to do that for a normal table. (1.4-alpha.06 is currently available, and hopefully 1.4 will come out today).

Comment: Normally a table only takes one dimension and a bunch of accessors for the columns, so I doubt this is the problem. You'd have to create 32 crossfilter dimensions (e.g. with `ndx.dimension()`) to trigger the crossfilter limit.